# How do I reconnect to my lost shell? (after a Terminal crash)

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, shell

I had some tabs in the Terminal and was doing some work when it crashed but my processes were still running (could see them in Activity Monitor/htop). When I started the Terminal again it put me to **ttys004** so I guess there are 3 more (4 if there should be a ttys000 too) sessions running.

How do I regain control over my lost sessions?

Answer (score 4):

Using screen would of saved you from this, man screen for more info on screen. It's briliant for long running process.

to start screen (or any command) when you create a new window or tab, add the command to the bottom of your ~/.bash_profile. eg: screen

Here is a copy of my ~/.screenrc , you might find some useful stuff in it http://pastebin.ca/1663824
screen also allows for tabs, the above version will create two bash login tabs,

Comment: I checked the manual and seems to be just what I need. Do you know if there is a way to run it every time I make a new tab in Terminal.app? I tried to put it in Setting > Shell > Startup > Run command but had no luck...

Comment: Something like http://tlug.dnho.net/?q=node/239 should work, with slight modifications if you are not using Bash as your login shell.

Comment: The first script of the post seems to not be working. The second though is really useful (with some modifications).